# Split array with array_chunk dynamically based on another array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to split an array in a dynamic way, like on the function `array_chunk` instead of the second parameter `int $size` to be allowed to add an array like `array different_sizes`

```
    $input_sub_arr = range('01', '15');
    $input_sub_array = array();
    foreach ($input_sub_arr as $answer) {
        $input_sub_array[] = 'answer-'.$answer;
    }
    var_Dump($input_sub_array);

$new_answer = array_chunk($input_sub_array, array(5, 6 , 2));
var_dump($new_answer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would be the goal of even doing that? Are you saying you want 3 arrays created, one with 5 items, followed by one with 6, followed by one with 2?

```php
function partition(array $values, array $sizes)
{
    $results = [];
    foreach ($sizes as $size) {
        $current = [];
        while (count($values) > 0 && count($current) < $size) {
            $current[] = array_unshift($values);
        }
        $results[] = $current;
    }
    return $results;
}

$result = partition($input_sub_arr, [5, 6, 2]);
// [['answer-01', 'answer-02', 'answer-03', 'answer-04', 'answer-05'], ['answer-06', 'answer-07', 'answer-08', 'answer-09', 'answer-10', 'answer-11'], ['answer-12', 'answer-13']]
```

Comment: Yes this is what I am saying

Comment: Hey could you have a look here also. I am strugeling for multi dimensional array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40721138/split-multidimensional-array-with-array-chunk-based-on-another-array