# Split multidimensional array with array_chunk based on another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to split a multi dimensional array based on another array of values
Something like `array_chunk($multi_array, array(1,3,7))`. Managed to find something related to this over here [array_chunk_multi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40716463/split-array-with-array-chunk-dynamically-based-on-another-array). Just that it doesn't work for multi dimensional array. Currently it splits them up correctly just that I get NULL to all values.

PHP

```
function array_chunk_array(array $values, array $sizes)
{
    $results = [];
    foreach ($sizes as $size) {
        $current = [];
        while (count($values) > 0 && count($current) < $size) {
            $current[] = array_unshift($values);
        }
        $results[] = $current;
    }
    return $results;
}   

$input_sub_arr = range('1', '6');
$input_sub_array = array();
foreach ($input_sub_arr as $answer) {
  $input_sub_array[] = 'answer-'.$answer;
}
$input_sub_answers = array();
foreach ($input_sub_array as $input_sub_answer) {
  $input_sub_answers[$input_sub_answer] = array('attributes' => array('correct'));
}
//var_dump($input_sub_answers);
$new_answer = array_chunk_array($input_sub_answers, array(4,2));
var_dump($new_answer);
```

CURRENT ARRAY

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(2) {

    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(2) {

    }
    ["answerText"]=>
    array(1) {

    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(2) {

    }
    ["answerText"]=>
    array(2) {

    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(2) {

    }
    ["answerText"]=>
    array(2) {

    }
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(2) {

    }
    ["answerText"]=>
    array(2) {

    }
  }
  [5]=>
  array(3) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(2) {

    }
    ["answerText"]=>
    array(2) {

    }
  }
}
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(2) {

    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(2) {

    }
    ["answerText"]=>
    array(1) {

    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(2) {

    }
    ["answerText"]=>
    array(2) {

    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(2) {

    }
    ["answerText"]=>
    array(2) {

    }
  }
}
array(2) {  
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(2) {

    }
    ["answerText"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["@attributes"]=>
      array(1) {

      }
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(2) {

    }
    ["answerText"]=>
    array(2) {

    }
  }
}
```

CURRENT OUTPUT

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    NULL
    [1]=>
    NULL
    [2]=>
    NULL
    [3]=>
    NULL
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    NULL
    [1]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

Comment: `array_chunk_array($input_sub_answers, array(4,2));` it should be  `array_chunk($input_sub_answers, array(4,2));`  and `array_chunk` need integer but your are given an array as it parameter.`array_chunk` is mandatory to use here?

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud I am trying to create a custom function `array_chunk_array` the version that accept an array as second parameter instead of integer.

Comment: Where you create `array_chunk_array` function? could you add this functions functionality?

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud Added. Needs to react like array_chunk, just that like as I said before.

Comment: Why you are using `array_unshift` ?  `array_unshift` need first value to prepand. I added `2` here is demo http://phpio.net/s/16n9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What really should be used here is [`array_splice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php):

```
$vl = [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3];
$sz = [4, 2, 3];
function array_chunk_array(array $values, array $sizes)
{
    $result = [];

    foreach ($sizes as $s) {
        $result[] = array_splice($values, 0, $s);
    }

    return $result;
}

echo'<pre>',print_r(array_chunk_array($vl, $sz)),'</pre>';
```